# Does "tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()" work for all classification problems?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

For `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()`, the documentation of TensorFlow says

`"Use this crossentropy loss function when there are two or more label classes."`

Since it covers two or more labels, including binary classification, then does it mean I can use this loss function for any classification problem? When do I **have to** use those binary loss such as `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy` and similar ones?

I am using TensorFlow 2.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BinaryCrossentropy ie like a special case of CategoricalCrossetropy with 2 classes, but BinaryCrossentropy is more efficient than CategoricalCrossentropy in calculation.
With CategoricalCrossentropy loss you should take the outputs as 2 dimension, while with BinaryCrossentropy 1 dimension is enough. It means you can reduce the weights by a half at the last layer with BinaryCrossentropy loss.

Comment: Thanks! So in theory the CategoricalCrossentropy should work for any classification problems, it is just BinaryCrossentropy could be faster when there are only 2 classes, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But almost the same.